# JUnit Test scheduled impact logic without using Thread.sleep

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, timertask, thread-sleep

I have a TimerTask implemented in my code. It periodically do some modification to the application logic. Now I want to test the impact of this TimerTask using JUnit. Say TimerTask is scheduled to run every 2 seconds, but I should run the test cases without using Thread.sleep.

```
public class LogService {

    public LogService() {
        configuration = ConfigurationUtil.getConfgiration();
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledAgent(), 0, configuration.getWaitTime());
    }

    private List<LoggingDetails> loggingDetails;

    public List<LoggingDetails> getLoggers() {
        return loggingDetails;

    }

    class ScheduledAgent extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // if time has taken more than wait time, then clear loggingDetails

        }
    }
}
```

One unit test scenario is that I get the loggingDetails within waitTime time period. This is okay to implement. The other scenario is that I should Test and confirm that after wait time, the list is cleaned and null.

Comment: I think we need more details about what your needs are, but you might want to look into [JMockit](http://jmockit.org) which I think lets you mock some system methods like `Thread.sleep` or methods that return the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would separate unit tests for `LogService` and `ScheduledAgent`.

Thus you will achieve that you could test actual logic of `ScheduledAgent`.

Another case is that in your test for `LogService` you must check that `scheduleAtFixedRate` method was ***called with correct parameters***. For that you could use some library like `JMockit` or `PowerMockito`. Most probably you would need to make `timer` as a field of the class to achieve the possibility to mock it. From my point of view, you don't need to test that `scheduleAtFixedRate` method is calling provided `TimerTask` periodically because this method is from JDK and for sure was already tested by thousands of developers.